# $\lim _{n\to \infty }n\sin\left(\frac{1}{\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil}\right)$ using Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }n\sin\left(\frac{1}{\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil}\right)$$

How can I use Taylor expansion to calculate this limit?

I subsituted $n=2m$

$$2\lim _{m\to \infty }m\sin\left(\frac{1}{\lceil{m}\rceil}\right)$$

Ihave never done a limit with the greatest integer function, but I can see that
$\frac{1}{\lceil{m}\rceil}\rightarrow0 $ when $m\rightarrow0$

So, if I know that $sin(t)=t+to(1), t\rightarrow0$ can I just say $2\lim _{m\to \infty }m\sin\left(\frac{1}{\lceil{m}\rceil}\right)=2\lim_m\to\infty m\left(\frac{1}{\lceil{m}\rceil}+\frac{1}{\lceil{m}\rceil}o(1)\right)$

I am tempted to cancel those "m", but I don't know if I am able to, how can I proceed?

Comment: There are two easy subsequences which approach lim sup and lim inf. Calculate both and you can show those are identical

Comment: Ignore the ceiling, it plays no role for large values of n. You're then left with the limit of n*sin(2/n) as n->infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have :

$$ n\sin{\frac{1}{\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil}} = n\sin{\frac{2}{n+2\epsilon_{n}}} $$
, where $\epsilon_{n}$ is bounded above by 1 and below by 0. Thus we have :

$$ n\sin{\frac{1}{\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil}} = n\sin{\frac{2}{n+2\epsilon_{n}}}$$ =

$$ \frac{2n}{n+2\epsilon_{n}}+o(\frac{2n}{n+2\epsilon_{n}}) = \frac{2n}{n+2\epsilon_{n}} + o(1) $$
, which goes to 2 as n approaches $\infty$.